# How to add chars in C?

Tags: c, char, int

So this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char username[100];
int password, i;
char temp;

printf("Enter username: ");
scanf("%s", username);
for(i=0;i < strlen(username);i++){
    printf("\n%d", username[i]);
    temp = username[i];
    password = password + temp;
}
printf("\n");
printf("Your password: %d", password);
return 0;
}
```

I know its a bit messy. I've spend HOURS trying to find out why this doesn't work, whereas this does:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char r = 'r';
char a = 'a';
char f = 'f';
int i;
i = r + a + f;
printf("%d", i);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_.

Comment: `printf("\n%d", username[i]);`...really?

Comment: well i guess that was it xD,

Comment: %d was for me to see if they are converted correctly

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What do you think it means to "add chars"?

Comment: i think it means to add their equivalent int's?

Comment: I really don't see how this code makes any sense.

Comment: Well first of all i'm new to C. Second, it's supposed to be a keygen for a simple crackme program.

Answer (score 0):

first of all learn the basics of C. you want to print out a decimal number with "%d". To output chars on console you need to use printf("%c", char_var). if its more than one character you need printf("%s", char[100]) (%s stands for string)

Comment: Ik i figured out i just didnt set password to 0. I MEANT to print out as an integer to see if they are converted correclty. thanks though :D

Comment: oh im sorry i didnt see.. you forgot to initalize the variable before using it. now i saw it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'scanf' to take string inputs. Use 'fgets'. Username array contains characters. You can't display them as integers. You can't sum up the characters.

Comment: but what if you do printf("%d", (charachter var)); , doesn't this print the char as an int?

Comment: Nonsense. `'a'` and `'r'` are perfectly valid integers that can be added like any other. How meaningful the result is is another question...